# Blog engine and Cloud Service integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, blogs

i don't know this  is the right way to explain this but here is the scenario.

i created a portal site`[Asp net MVC4]` and deployed on windows azure as cloud service say `abc.com` now business guy comes and says i need to write the blog to promote it . So i hosted a word press or any blog engine site for him say  `blog.abc.com`.

problem comes here , how can i make this `abc.com/blog/Some blog starts here` ?

By custom domain and redirection, i can't achieve this [Not Sure].

the only way i see is.  *Write a  REST Service to talk with blog database ,Create a Area in project 'Blog' and Display the Content*.

Answer (score 0):

you can host the blog in a subdirectory abc.com/blog/ if windows azure allows php to be installed. it just requires additional configuration in your web.config file to stop your application from trying to process requests to /blog/